# how to run app in background react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I built a step tracking app with react-native that need to count steps whether the app in background or foreground. Counted steps need to update real time to the database. And also need to view ongoing notification with counted steps. However this only works when the app is in the foreground and it tested on an Android device. I used react-native-background-action package and the app stopped working when it keeping several hours in the background. Steps are not counting and updating. Also I tried react-native-background-fetch, react-native-background-job and react-native background task packages but same result. I want to know how to successfully run react-native applications in background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Headless JS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android.html) API**,it is only for android.
**Headless JS is a way to run JavaScript tasks in the background.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already used several packages that use Headless JS in their package. I thought they would be useful. But it is not. So it is better to try Headless JS directly in the app. I will try it.